# Component is not a known element

Tags: angular

I have a component that is in a `shared` module, and I'm successfully using that component inside another, however, when I try to use it in a second component I'm seeing the following error;

```
ERROR in src/app/dashboard/dashboard-report/dashboard-report.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-header-unauthenticated' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header-unauthenticated' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header-unauthenticated' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I've looked over what I've done and I can't see to see where I am going wrong.

I have a module called `shared` which has a component called `header-unauthenticated` which is exported so it can be used inside other modules/components. Here is the `shared` module;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AlertComponent,
    HeaderUnauthenticatedComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AlertComponent,
    HeaderUnauthenticatedComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

I'm trying to use the `header-unauthenticated` component inside a component called `dashboard-report` which is inside another module `dashboard`. I have imported the `shared` module into the `dashboard` module so that it's components can be used, but they don't seem to work. Here is the `dashboard` module;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardReportComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

I have another module `access` and a component inside it `login`, where I am able to use the `header-unauthenticated` component without issue, and comparing the `access` module with the `dashboard` module I can't see any differences.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class AccessModule { }
```

Where am I going wrong, why is the `header-unauthenticated` component not found?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the `dashboard` component wasn't being imported into the `app.module.ts` file, adding it fixed the problem;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AccessModule,
    DashboardModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```